# Cannot insert entities by EFCore.BulkExtensions.BulkInsert with Exception: The given key 'xxx' was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I tried to insert bulk data using `EFCore.BulkExtensions.BulkInsert`, I encountered the following exception:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'EnglishWordId' was not present in the dictionary.
         at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
         at EFCore.BulkExtensions.TableInfo.LoadData[T](DbContext context, Type type, IEnumerable`1 entities, Boolean loadOnlyPKColumn)
         at EFCore.BulkExtensions.TableInfo.CreateInstance[T](DbContext context, Type type, IEnumerable`1 entities, OperationType operationType, BulkConfig bulkConfig)
         at EFCore.BulkExtensions.DbContextBulkTransaction.ExecuteAsync[T](DbContext context, Type type, IEnumerable`1 entities, OperationType operationType, BulkConfig bulkConfig, Action`1 progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Identity.Controllers.ImportDictionaryController.ImportDictionaryToDatabase(String connectionId, Stream stream) in C:\Code\Dotnet\Identity\Identity\Controllers\ImportDictionaryController.cs:line 56
         at Identity.Controllers.ImportDictionaryController.UploadDictionaryFile() in C:\Code\Dotnet\Identity\Identity\Controllers\ImportDictionaryController.cs:line 37
         at Identity.Controllers.ImportDictionaryController.UploadDictionaryFile() in C:\Code\Dotnet\Identity\Identity\Controllers\ImportDictionaryController.cs:line 37
// ...
```

I am trying to import parsed CSV data into the database using EFCore.

This is a part of the code I tried to insert data into database:

```
var words = await csv.GetRecordsAsync<EnglishWord>().ToListAsync();

long totalCount = words.Count;
for (int count = 0; count < totalCount; count += 100)
{
    var inserted = words.Skip(count).Take(100);
    await _dictionaryContext.BulkInsertAsync(inserted, config =>
    {
        config.PreserveInsertOrder = true;
        config.SetOutputIdentity = true;
    });
    // Console.WriteLine($"({connectionId}) Processing: {count} / {totalCount}");
}
```

This is the relevant definition of my entity class, and the database has completed migration and update.

```
public class EnglishWord
{
    public long EnglishWordId;
    public string Word = null!; 
    public string? Phonetic; 
    public string? Definition; 
    public string Translation = null!;
}
```

**NOTE:** `var words = await csv.GetRecordsAsync<EnglishWord>().ToListAsync();` **WILL NOT** set the id for each EnglishWord, which means `words[0] = ... words[n-1].EnglishId = 0 (defalut value)`

How can I do to solve this problem :(

I expect that when EFCore is inserted, it can automatically assign an Id to each entity, regardless of whether its Id is set or not?

Comment: EFCore has no build-in BulkInsertAsync method,are you working with third party tool?